# Как получить значение после выполнения oracle процедуры?

Tags: python, oracle

Пытаюсь посредством python библиотеки `cx_Oracle` выполнить oracle процедуру:

```sql
DECLARE
        num_N_SUBJECT_ID SI_V_SUBJECTS.N_SUBJECT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SI_PERSONS_PKG.SI_PERSONS_PUT(
        num_N_SUBJECT_ID       => num_N_SUBJECT_ID,
END;
```

При таком действии система назначит автоматом новый id.

Как посредством данной библиотеки и python я могу в отчет после выполнения получить `num_N_SUBJECT_ID`? Что бы я не делал то получаю либо ошибку либо `None`.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Значения получают путём выполнения запроса SELECT. Неужели у вставленной записи нет такого поля или выражения, которое в условии отбора позволит получить именно эту свежевставленную запись?

Comment: Не берусь однозначно утверждать, но по идее процедуры не должны возвращать значения, хотя могут. А вот функции созданы чтобы возвращать значения после выполнения. И то, и то подпрограммы. Для подпрограмм делается это определяя выходные параметры через OUT. См 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/formal_parameter.htm#LNPLS1271 и https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336